# Error en php mysql tengo valores vacios, asignarle valores para insertar en tabla

Tags: php, mysql

tengo este error por fa, como pongo valores a las variables para que no salgan vacias

> Error: INSERT INTO `contratista` (`contratista_nombre`, `contratista_tipdoc`, `contratista_numdoc`, `contratista_ut`, `contratista_socio1`, `contratista_socio1_porcentaje`, `contratista_socio2`, `contratista_socio2_porcentaje`, `contratista_socio3`, `contratista_socio3_porcentaje`, `contratista_socio4`, `contratista_socio4_porcentaje`, `contratista_direccion`, `contratista_mail`, `contratista_paginaweb`) VALUES ( dmdpdpkd, NIT, NIT, NO, , , , , , , , , , hola@hola.com, )You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , , , , ' at line 7

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'p_contratos', '3306');

    if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    mysqli_query($conn, 'SET NAMES \'utf8\'');


$contratista_nombre     = $_POST['contratistanombre'];
$contratista_tipdoc     = $_POST['contratista_tipdoc'];
$contratista_numdocet   = $_POST['contratista_numdoc'];
$contratista_ut         = $_POST['contratista_ut'];
$contratista_socio1     = $_POST['contratista_socio1'];
$contratista_socio1_porcentaje  = $_POST['contratista_socio1_porcentaje'];
$contratista_socio2     = $_POST['contratista_socio2'];
$contratista_socio2_porcentaje  = $_POST['contratista_socio2_porcentaje'];
$contratista_socio3     = $_POST['contratista_socio3'];
$contratista_socio3_porcentaje  = $_POST['contratista_socio3_porcentaje'];
$contratista_socio4     = $_POST['contratista_socio4'];
$contratista_socio4_porcentaje  = $_POST['contratista_socio4_porcentaje'];
$contratista_direccion  = $_POST['contratista_direccion'];
$contratista_mail       = $_POST['contratista_mail'];
$contratista_paginaweb  = $_POST['contratista_paginaweb'];

$sql = ("INSERT INTO `contratista` (`contratista_nombre`, `contratista_tipdoc`, `contratista_numdoc`, `contratista_ut`, `contratista_socio1`, `contratista_socio1_porcentaje`, `contratista_socio2`, `contratista_socio2_porcentaje`, `contratista_socio3`, `contratista_socio3_porcentaje`, `contratista_socio4`, `contratista_socio4_porcentaje`, `contratista_direccion`, `contratista_mail`, `contratista_paginaweb`)
        VALUES (
                $contratista_nombre,
                $contratista_tipdoc,
                $contratista_tipdoc,
                $contratista_ut,
                $contratista_socio1,
                $contratista_socio1_porcentaje,
                $contratista_socio2,
                $contratista_socio2_porcentaje,
                $contratista_socio3,
                $contratista_socio3_porcentaje,
                $contratista_socio4,
                $contratista_socio4_porcentaje,
                $contratista_direccion,
                $contratista_mail,
                $contratista_paginaweb
                )");

//$consulta = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
//var_dump($sql);
//die();

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Estás en [es.so]. Tu pregunta debes escribirla en castellano. Traduce tu pregunta o terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: el fallo parece en la sql. los valores de los campos que son tipo cadena tienes que ponerlos en cadena, y por lo que veo, al menos el nombre (y seguro que alguno mas) los tienes sin '' en la parte de valor.

Comment: Los valores los estás enviando desde un formulario. Cierto? Empecemos por ahí.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes realmente, es como agregas las variables a la sentencia SQL para insertarlas... Como dice el error, el error lo tienes por que la sentencia dice algo como:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (...valores...) VALUES ,,,,,;
```

Esto es por que no agregaste las comillas que encierran una cadena de texto como tal para mandarla a ejecución.

```
INSERT INTO tabla (cadena1, cadena2, int1, int2, cadena3) VALUES '', '', 0, 0, '';
```

**Prueba a realizar un echo de $sql y veras de que hablo**

Entonces lo que está mal en realidad, es tu query... pero igual puedes setear valores default de ingreso para tu tabla.

Hay varias formas de hacerlo y asignarle un valor a la variable la verdad.

Tienes la opción de agregar un predeterminado en la columna de servidor.
O tienes la opción de tu hacer un predeterminado en php.

Por ejemplo, en php:

```
<?php
  $variable = ""; //Variable inicializada vacía
  if(!empty($_POST["variable"])){ //Si la variable POST NO viene vacia
    $variable = $_POST["variable"]; //carga el valor en la variable
  }
?>
```

De este modo, la variable se carga con un valor, en este caso una cadena vacía.

Luego, es cosa de pasarla correctamente en la sentencia:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tabla (variable) VALUES '$variable'";
```

Comment: si @excorpion los valores vienen vacios por que en el fomrulario no todas las veces se insertan datos

Comment: Si vienen vacíos, haz lo del ejemplo en php... inicializa la variable en modo vacío, evalúa el POST, y si viene vacío, lo insertas vacío.

Answer (score -1):

amigos quedó asi

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'p_secop_1', '3306');

    if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    mysqli_query($conn, 'SET NAMES \'utf8\'');


$contratista_nombre     = $_POST['contratistanombre'];
$contratista_tipdoc     = $_POST['contratista_tipdoc'];
$contratista_numdocet   = $_POST['contratista_numdoc'];
$contratista_ut         = $_POST['contratista_ut'];

$contratista_socio1 = ""; //Variable inicializada vacía
  if(!empty($_POST['contratista_socio1'])){ //Si la variable POST NO viene vacia
    $contratista_socio1 = $_POST['contratista_socio1']; //carga el valor en la variable
  }else{
    $contratista_socio1 = " ";
  }

$contratista_socio1_porcentaje  = "";
  if(!empty($_POST['contratista_socio1_porcentaje'])){ //Si la variable POST NO viene vacia
    $contratista_socio1_porcentaje = $_POST["contratista_socio1_porcentaje"]; //carga el valor en la variable
  }else{
    $contratista_socio1_porcentaje = " ";
  }

$contratista_socio2 = ""; //Variable inicializada vacía
  if(!empty($_POST["contratista_socio2"])){ //Si la variable POST NO viene vacia
    $contratista_socio2 = $_POST["contratista_socio2"]; //carga el valor en la variable
  }else{
    $contratista_socio2 = " ";
  }
  
$contratista_socio2_porcentaje  = "";
  if(!empty($_POST["contratista_socio2_porcentaje"])){ //Si la variable POST NO viene vacia
    $contratista_socio2_porcentaje = $_POST["contratista_socio2_porcentaje"]; //carga el valor en la variable
  }else{
    $contratista_socio2_porcentaje = " ";
  }
  
$contratista_socio3 = ""; //Variable inicializada vacía
  if(!empty($_POST["contratista_socio3"])){ //Si la variable POST NO viene vacia
    $contratista_socio3 = $_POST["contratista_socio3"]; //carga el valor en la variable
  }else{
    $contratista_socio3 = " ";
  }
  
$contratista_socio3_porcentaje  = "";
  if(!empty($_POST["contratista_socio3_porcentaje"])){ //Si la variable POST NO viene vacia
    $contratista_socio3_porcentaje = $_POST["contratista_socio3_porcentaje"]; //carga el valor en la variable
  }else{
    $contratista_socio3_porcentaje = " ";
  }

$contratista_socio4 = ""; //Variable inicializada vacía
  if(!empty($_POST["contratista_socio4"])){ //Si la variable POST NO viene vacia
    $contratista_socio4 = $_POST["contratista_socio4"]; //carga el valor en la variable
  }else{
    $contratista_socio4 = " ";
  }
  
$contratista_socio4_porcentaje  = "";
  if(!empty($_POST["contratista_socio4_porcentaje"])){ //Si la variable POST NO viene vacia
    $contratista_socio4_porcentaje = $_POST["contratista_socio4_porcentaje"]; //carga el valor en la variable
  }else{
    $contratista_socio4_porcentaje = " ";
  }


$contratista_direccion  = $_POST['contratista_direccion'];
$contratista_mail       = $_POST['contratista_mail'];

$contratista_paginaweb  = "";
  if(!empty($_POST["contratista_paginaweb"])){ //Si la variable POST NO viene vacia
    $contratista_paginaweb = $_POST["contratista_paginaweb"]; //carga el valor en la variable
  }else{
    $contratista_paginaweb = null;
  }

$sql = "INSERT INTO `contratista` ( `contratista_nombre`, `contratista_tipdoc`, `contratista_numdoc`, `contratista_ut`, `contratista_socio1`, `contratista_socio1_porcentaje`, `contratista_socio2`, `contratista_socio2_porcentaje`, `contratista_socio3`, `contratista_socio3_porcentaje`, `contratista_socio4`, `contratista_socio4_porcentaje`, `contratista_direccion`, `contratista_mail`, `contratista_paginaweb`)
        VALUES(                     '$contratista_nombre', '$contratista_tipdoc', '$contratista_numdocet', '$contratista_ut', '$contratista_socio1', '$contratista_socio1_porcentaje', '$contratista_socio2', '$contratista_socio2_porcentaje', '$contratista_socio3', '$contratista_socio3_porcentaje ', '$contratista_socio4', '$contratista_socio4_porcentaje', '$contratista_direccion', '$contratista_mail', '$contratista_paginaweb')";

//$consulta = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
//var_dump($sql);
//die();

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Intenta explicar cómo resolviste

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero para que realmente sea considerada una buena respuesta necesita de una breve explicación de los cambios realizados para que todos podamos entenderlos. En caso contrario es una respuesta considerada de baja calidad y podria recibir votos negativos.